# iTerm2 now starts up listing profile configuration

Tags: zsh, macos-big-sur, iterm2

Recently, when I load iTerm2 on my mac, it lists out the configuration of my profile (or possibly its something different).

This is what I see:

```
Last login: Tue Jun 21 19:54:38 on ttys000COLORFGBG='15;0'
COLORTERM=truecolor
COMMAND_MODE=unix2003
HOME=/Users/me
ITERM_PROFILE=Default
ITERM_SESSION_ID=w0t0p0:FD9764B1-4535-4FE2-932A-97AFD9D6C804
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_TERMINAL=iTerm2
LC_TERMINAL_VERSION=3.4.15
LOGNAME=me
OLDPWD=/Users/me
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
PWD=/Users/me
SHELL=/bin/zsh
SHLVL=1
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.u21pRFo1wk/Listeners
TERM=xterm
TERM_PROGRAM=iTerm.app
TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION=3.4.15
TERM_SESSION_ID=w0t0p0:FD9764B1-4535-4FE2-932A-97AFD9D6C804
TMPDIR=/var/folders/dz/wvb1lxq56wg_wk3ppwqw4mdc0000gn/T/
USER=me
XPC_FLAGS=0x0
XPC_SERVICE_NAME=0
__CFBundleIdentifier=com.googlecode.iterm2
__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING=0x0:0:0
me@my-iMac ~ %
```

I don't really like this behaviour.  I can't find where that has been set to happen. I can't see anything in .zshenv, .zshrc, .bashrc and can't see where in iTerm such a thing might be triggered. I've tried creating a new profile, but that also results in the same output.

Any other suggestions to how I can get back to the way it was a few weeks back where it just told me the last time I logged in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add `set -x` to ~/.zshenv, the shell will print every line it runs with file names and line numbers. You can then find the offending command and remove or fix it. My best guess would be a call to export without any arguments: something like `export $foo`, where `$foo` is empty?

Comment: Thanks - somehow a new line had crept into an export statement.  Removed that and iTerm is behaving as I expected now!